# JPQL query where clause using IN, How to pass the parameter to the query

Tags: java, jpql

I have JPQL query, I am getting empty result for the below query. Please see the attached code

```
String names = "'laptop','mobile'"; 
LoadContext testDataQuery = LoadContext.create(testData.class);
testDataQuery.setQuery(LoadContext.createQuery(
         "select pd from demo$TestData pd where pd.dataName.name in (:names)")
    .setParameter("measures", names)); 

List testDataQueryList = dataManager.loadList(testDataQuery); // Here I am getting empty list.
```

Please say me, How to pass the names to JPQL where clasue for In.

Thanks!!

Comment: Put your database DDL in the question and format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List` for `IN` parameters instead of `String`. Your example should work if you change the `names` declaration to this:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("laptop", "mobile");
```

and keep everything else as is.

Note that you can also remove the parenthesis in the `IN` clause

```
pd.dataName.name in :names
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `List` of names into `setParameter` method.